# SQL Syntax highligther in Java

Tags: java, jsf, syntax-highlighting, zk, syntaxhighlighter

I am looking some good Sql Syntax highlighter which will easily integrated with Component based(`JSF,ZK` ) framework. Any idea which will be best for me i tried [Codeirror](https://code.google.com/p/zk-codemirror/issues/detail?id=7) but binding is not working. Any one suggest some other which will easily integrated.  I do not want to open output in JFrame or Applet its should be in Browser

Comment: This is what stackoverflow uses. http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

Comment: @Deepak how you will do Binding here?

Comment: Include the script in your html and use pre tags. Here's the sql example.http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/prettify_test.html#sql_lang

Comment: I got it but how would we bind the values? Mean which we would written in betwwen those tag i have t save into Database

Comment: you can print the value inside the pre tag with jsp or servlet or whatever serverside language you are using. Jquery is another alternative to append inside the pre tag.

Answer (score 1):

Using [prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) is a good solution, but this is a JavaScript library working client-side in the browser.

If you want to send your source code (java, sql, python, bash, html, xml, css, javascript...) prepared server-side as HTML code with `span` tags to color the text (i.e. syntax highligthing) in pure Java, you can use [java-prettify](https://code.google.com/p/java-prettify/). This is a port of the Javascript lib in java.

I have explained how you can use the parser to produce highligthed HTML code here: [use the parser to create HTML](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/java-prettify/AANTzgRe81k). Have a look at the code in the java class `PrettifyToHtml` and at the example.

Comment: @Jmni Ok let us suppose i will go with this so i have to write Java classes as well or Just put jar and call some method it will work?

Comment: You need the JavaPrettify-1.2.1.jar and the methods I have written in the attached PrettifyToHtml.java